# Oracle, archive a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm no DBA expert by any means, and im just used to doing the basic tasks. With the risk of sounding like a mega-noob at this, I was given a certain task:

> Can you create the archive table for this and export the table to create scripts to create and drop the table

What would this mean exactly?

Is there a way to do this in SQL Developer?

Comment: Ask for more precise requirements maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this link can help regarding "archive table" : http://dbaforums.org/oracle/lofiversion/index.php?t10815.html

Exporting a table is done by right clicking on the table, and then click on Export